# Riemann Dashboard not outputting internal Riemann metrics

Tags: clojure, riemann, riemann-dashboard

I'm new to `Riemann` and also new to `ruby` and `Clojure` as well. I'm trying to output the internal riemann events via `(streams prn)` in my `riemann.config` file. I currently see messages being printed out in the terminal from where I launched `riemann`.

Ex:

```
#riemann.codec.Event{:host "localhost.localdomain", :service "riemann server ws 0.0.0.0:5556 in latency 0.999", :state "ok", :description nil, :metric nil, :tags nil, :time 283857867047/200, :ttl 20}
```

In my dashboard however I'm unable to get these to print to any sort of log or gauge.

I tried using the following as a `service =~ "riemann %"` from [here](http://riemann.io/howto.html#instrumenting-your-systems)

I get an orange message displaying `1 socket errors; check the server field above` or a large question market above the title.

Not sure what else to try or do from here to identify what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The riemann dashboard displays events in the index, which `prn` does not update. Use `(streams index)` to capture the events for the dashboard.

Comment: Ah this was it! I needed to update my `riemann.config` to use index and not prn